# content-type for BlackBerry OTA installation

Tags: blackberry

For BlackBerry OTA installation what content-type should be used for jad and cod files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-139239.html

> the MIME types for .jad and .cod files, text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor and application/vnd.rim.cod respectively.

Comment: thankq 4 ur reply.my problem is how to set url for this two files

Comment: Then you should have asked that question. The URL to each file would depend on your specific web server installation.

Comment: I think Aswan and MaheshBabu are working on the same project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074827/blackberry-ota-downloader-using-servlets

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to a .htaccess when using apache for your OTA deployment:

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor .jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod .cod
AddType application/java-archive .jar
```