# Blackberry OTA downloader using Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, blackberry

I want to setup a Blackberry OTA downloader using Servlets. How do I set the URL for `.jad` and `.cod` files? [I have set the content type for both files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069261/content-type-for-blackberry-ota-installation). How do I send both files to the client when I receive a request from the client? Do I need to create two servlets or is one enough?

Comment: "I want to inflate a bicycle tire using a potato."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a servlet for this. A servlet is only useful if those files are dynamically generated or are not directly public accessible (i.e. those files are not in public webcontent).

The simplest way would be to put those files in the public webcontent (there where you would usually place the JSP/HTML files) and configure the appropriate mime mapping in your servletcontainer's or webapp's `web.xml` file.

```
<mime-mapping>
   <extension>jad</extension>
   <mime-type>text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
   <extension>cod</extension>
   <mime-type>application/vnd.rim.cod</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Then the servletcontainer will automatically set the correct content type when the client requests the files directly by e.g. http://example.com/file.jad and http://example.com/file.cod.